# How to assign correct ids to html elements?

Tags: html

Let's say, if I need to assign an id to element with first name, should it be named like:

1. firstName
2. first-name
3. first_name

Which option should I choose (every id I posted above is allowed, but what is the recommended naming)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely up to your taste. I prefer hyphenated ids and classes, because it potentially allows you to use the [css3-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation) `[att|=val]`

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't matter really, only thing they must be unique, and if you'll handle those ids with javascript later on (get contents to ajax calls) for exmaple, try to use kind of a delimiter for your own convenience

Answer (score 2):

I like `first-name`.

It differentiates your ID from JavaScript (and other languages) being an illegal variable name and it's faster to type since you don't have to use the shift key.

Answer (score -2):

```
firstName: usually your model layer, Java, C#, C++
first_name: usually Database or View layer, JSP, GSP, HTML, ETC

first-name: Not valid
```

Comment: He's talking about HTML element IDs, not variable names.

Comment: every try doing this? <script>alert(first-name)<script>, because you can refer to an element by it's ID in javascript

Comment: really @Christoph? you can? if you have <input id="first"><input id="name"><input id="first-name">, and you think inside js, u can select first-name correctly without doing a document.getElementByID vs actually accessing it by its name. Not all environment allows u to use 3rd part js library such as jquery.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact, that hyphenated ids are allowed and thus, your answer is wrong: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp
Btw.the only correct way to select such an element is: document.getElementById! all others are not crossbrowser-compatible and risky.